# Command `ip a show` in `zsh` not working

Tags: 18.04, zsh

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 distro in which I use `zsh` as default shell instead of `bash`.

Since I like the Kali Linux `zsh` setup, I copied the `.zshrc` config file to the Ubuntu machine and my shell seems to work right.

Still a problem arises: when I launch the `ip a show` command, I get as output:

```bsh
Option "-color=auto" is unknown, try "ip -help".
```

I tried to google the error, but I cannot find anything useful.

Does anyone know where the problem lies? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an alias in your zsh configuration. Check with the `alias` command and/or with `which ip`.

*Happy 20+ years zsh user here.*  ;-)

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.